# How do I find out which pipelines have been used for creating a view?

Tags: mongodb, view, mongodb-.net-driver

What is the shell command for finding out which pipelines have been used for creating a certain view? MongoDB version is 3.6.4

Also, is there a way of getting the pipelines with the .net driver, version 2.6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`db.getCollectionInfos()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/), and optionally specify a "filter" condition as a query.

For example:

```
// Insert Collection
db.test.insert({ "a": 1 })

// Create a view
db.createView("testView", "test", [{ "$match": { } }]);


// Get the information
db.getCollectionInfos({ "name": "testView" })
[
        {
                "name" : "testView",
                "type" : "view",
                "options" : {
                        "viewOn" : "test",
                        "pipeline" : [
                                {
                                        "$match" : {

                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "info" : {
                        "readOnly" : true
                }
        }
]
```

Note that `"name"` matches a specific collection, and you can optionally even filter for `"view"` on the `"type"` field to get all views. The pipeline is clearly displayed in the returned output.

Note also this "shell method" just wraps the [`listCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) system command. Most drivers have some variant of this method on the "database" object or they can otherwise just invoke the command with options.